# how to skip email confirmation using devise_token_auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, devise-confirmable

I'm using devise_token_auth gem for my Rails app. I want to login into application once the user sign_up is done. How can I skip confirmation.

I tried `config.reconfirmable = false` but no luck

Can anyone suggest me or help me how can I achieve this?
I tried the solution provided

[Why won't Devise allow unconfirmed users to login even when allow_unconfirmed_access_for is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083887/why-wont-devise-allow-unconfirmed-users-to-login-even-when-allow-unconfirmed-ac)
 But still ending up with

```
{"success":false,"errors":["A confirmation email was sent to your account at test123@gmail.com. You must follow the instructions in the email before your account can be activated"]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following callback the model definition:

```
before_save -> { skip_confirmation! }
```

And remove `:confirmable` from included devise modules:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable,
         :trackable, :validatable, :registerable,
         :omniauthable # there is no :confirmable here
```

Comment: deleting `:confirmable` migrations and `devise :confirmable` was enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to skip sending email confirmation for some people but keep sending it for other (based on email address for example) you can do something like that.

```
# app/models/user.rb
after_create :skip_confirmation_email_for_some_user

# ...

protected
  def skip_confirmation_email_for_some_user
    if self.email.include? "noconfirm"
      self.skip_confirmation!
      self.confirm
    end
  end
```

*Tested on Rails 5.1.6 and Devise Token Auth 0.2.0*

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has this error,`include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User` should be after `devise :database_authenticable...` https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/397#issuecomment-166113011