# Setting different config for scoped devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In a rails app what would be the way to set different config values based on `devise` model? 
Lets say we have 2 models Admin & User. Setting config values in devise.rb will be applied in all models. How can I set a different config to one of the model?
I tried like this

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  self.allow_unconfirmed_access_for =0.days
end
```

but getting error `can't modify frozen class`
How can I fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message looks more specific to your *application code* than to the *devise*. 

I would suggest to check whether you have deliberately frozen the `Admin` class anywhere in your code.

*Note: I tried the same and did not receive any error (I did not try the complete functionality though)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an existing StackOverflow post about your issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083887/why-wont-devise-allow-unconfirmed-users-to-login-even-when-allow-unconfirmed-ac). Apparently, you can override `confirmation_required?` method in `Admin` model and return `false` to skip the confirmation steps for Admin. Please note that it will skip sending the registration email for `Admin` too.

**UPDATE:**

`self.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = ...` or `Admin.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = ...` works but for old devise versions.

For recent versions it is `Devise.allow_unconfirmed_access_for =...` (I think this is what you are looking for)

Answer (score -1):

Make Admin the inheritor of the User class. Then already delimit access rights for the User and for the Admin

Comment: What you are suggesting is not clear. From what I understand you are suggesting to inherit from the user model. But what's the purpose of inheriting another model? The main objective of creating separate devise models is for the logic separation(abstraction) from each other